# Could be any propagation of $_GET variabiles in a short way?

Tags: php, get

I'm editing a website made form another programmer, i see he uses short php tags 
`<?` instead of `<?php`
or
`<?=` instead of `<?php echo`

is there any way to assign `$_GET` variabiles in a short way?
I see he is using `$id` instead of `$_GET['$id']`

i'm changing domain on his website from `www.mydomain.com` to `www.yourdomain.com/folder`

The problem brons in this circumstance, in a page with this address:

`www.yourdomain.com/folder/foto.php?id=http://www.yourdomain.com/folder/img/imagename.jpg`

He retrives the id variable in this way:

foto.php:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta content="">
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="Black">
  <?
    session_start();
    include "config.php";
$id=strip_tags($id);
    ?>



  <table  align="center"><tr><td>
<img src="<?=$id?>" align="left" border="0">
</td></tr></table>  
  </body>
</html>
```

config.php:

```
<?
$db_host = "??.??.??.??";  
$db_user = "??????";       
$db_password = "?????";   
$db_name = "?????";       

//db connect
$conn = @mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password)
or die
("connection error");
$db = @mysql_select_db($db_name,$conn);

?>
```

But it only works on the old domain, in the new domain it cannot retrive the $id variable!

I know that if i change $id with $_GET['$id'] the problem is solved, but i can't figure out how it can work in the old domain!

```
Old Domain = PHP 4.4.9

New Domain = PHP 5.3.28
```

Comment: `register_globals` must be turned on at the old domain. It's no longer enable by default in later versions of PHP (because it's seen to be very bad - because it allows anyone to inject variables into your script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That variable is available because the `register_globals` directive is enabled in `php.ini`.

**A basic explanation:**

`register_globals` registers `$_REQUEST` super global array elements as variables. For example if you submit a value in a form, via `POST` or `GET` request methods, with an input field name `id`, PHP will automatically register a variable `$id` and assign it value of the input field `id`.

This is what you're seeing at your old domain.

In newer versions of PHP this is disabled by default (and now removed) because it allows anyone to inject variables into your script.

According to [the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) this directive is removed as of version 5.4 but it's been turned off by default for considerably longer.

Comment: Thank you very much, i found this propagation in many pages i need to fix this enabling register_globals, but looking to this article:
http://mrphp.com.au/blog/how-enable-register-globals-php-5#comment-5130
i can solve it only with the coded solution... so weird!